# Can I use code splitting to migrate from an older version of Vuetify to a newer version?

Tags: vuetify.js, code-splitting

We have a vue.js project in which we are using Vuetify 1.5.2. We want to upgrade to the latest version of Vuetify. Our first attempt to do this proved disastrous as it is an all-or-nothing move and as soon as we upgraded our version of Vuetify, everything across the site broke.

Now we are considering this again but we are looking at code splitting. What we are wondering is can code splitting be used to slowly migrate from Vuetify 1.5.2 to the latest version (2.3.19 right now)? Can we package our code in such a way that newer code is packaged the latest version of Vuetify but older code is packaged with the older version of Vuetify?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it will result in even more conflicts, and more time to ensure specific parts call the older version and some the newer. I'm afraid you will have to go the painful route of branching your project and slowly go through all the Vuetify issues.

Unless your front-end consists of multiple independent projects (each with their own package.json), then it could be done.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Thanks Jason.